# Http Request - Should I reload the eloquent model information inside a Http Request Life Cycle?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, httprequest, eloquent-relationship

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#refreshing-models

> If you already have an instance of an Eloquent model that was
> retrieved from the database, you can "**refresh**" the model using the
> **fresh** and **refresh** methods. The fresh method will **re-retrieve** the model
> from the database. The existing model instance will not be affected:

```
$flight = Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
$freshFlight = $flight->fresh();
```

> The refresh method will **re-hydrate** the existing model using
> **fresh data from the database**. In addition, all of its loaded relationships will be refreshed as well:

```
$flight = Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
$flight->number = 'FR 456';
$flight->refresh();
$flight->number; // "FR 900"
```

All the time (regularly) I make my requests by querying the models and relations **only once** for a normal http request (e.g. post-redirect-get or simply for a get).

**When** should I reload the relation or model information?

I feel that **I have done my requests wrong** after seeing this part of the Laravel documentation.

Could you give me some **use cases** for `fresh`()/`refresh`()? Please

Is there something that escapes my knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresh and refresh are used when your model might have been change since it's first query

exemple :

```
// The passenger is in the FR 900 Flight
$passenger = Passenger::with('flight')->find(1);

// dd($passenger->flight->number); => FR 900

$flight = Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();
$flight->number = 'FR 456';
$flight->save();

// dd($passenger->flight->number); => FR 900


$passenger->flight->fresh(); // Refresh Only the flight
// OR
$passenger->refresh(); // Refresh The Passenger AND ALL his relationships (his flight)

// dd($passenger->flight->number); => FR 456
```

The fresh method will get only the model it's been called
The refresh method will make a fresh() on the model and all it's loaded relationships

Comment: thanks. When 1) I query a model/relationship and 2) then do processing that takes considerable time for example (but does not modify the model/relationship) and 3) go back to work with that model/relationships, is reloading necessary (**due to the time it took for the previous processing**), or only **when there are actually modifications** to the data involved? @Mathieu Ferre

Comment: You only need to use them IF your model might have change when you need it.

Remember that you have a different instance of your object each time you query it.

You might want to use the setRelation() method ($passenger->setRelation('flight', $flight);) If you want to keep manipulating the same object.

YOU DON'T HAVE TO reload your object if all your modifications are in the context of the same instance

Comment: Tbanks +1 "YOU DON'T HAVE TO reload your object if all your modifications are in the context of the same instance" - In the example you gave me in the answer, it was necessary to `refresh/fresh` because I modified the relationship, that is, I made modifications **to another instance**, right? @Mathieu Ferre

Comment: yes it is, don't forget to accept my answer to close your question :)